# Subsets of universal sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Was going through previous exam questions and came across this:

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be subsets of a universal set $U$ and suppose $n(U) = 100$, $n(A) = 31$, $n(B) = 34$, $n(C) = 35$,
$n(A \cap B) = 12$, $n(A\cap C) = 10$, $n(B \cap C) = 17$, and $n(A \cap B \cap C)$ = 6.

1. What is ($A′ \cap B \cap C$)?
2. What is ($A \cup B \cup C$)?

Comment: you can draw a Venn diagram or  directly use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 1):

Let A, B, and C be subsets of a universal set U and suppose $$|U| = 100, \; |A| = 31, \; |B| = 34, \; |C| = 35, \\|A \cap B| = 12, \; |A \cap C| = 10, \; |B \cap C| = 17,\\ |A \cap B \cap C| = 6$$

> 1.What is $|\overline{A} \cap B \cap C|$?

Exclude the intersection.

$|\overline{A} \cap B \cap C| = |B\cap C| - |A \cap B\cap C|$

> 2.What is $|A \cup B \cup C|$?

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

$|A\cup B \cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| - |B\cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|$

Comment: Whats with all this + and - stuff?

Comment: @user3458730 - in your question you write $n(U)=100$; is this meaning the number of elements of $U$ ? In Graham's answer, the number of menebers of $A$ is (more "formally") written as $|A|$. Thus, $+$ and $-$ are "standard" arithmetical operations on numbers. When you ask "What is (A'∩B∩C)?" you are askin - we presume - about the number of memebers of this set, because you do not give us info about its members : so the above answer.